# Chart.JS Label string cannot accept ViewBag Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm developing a simple application in ASP.NET Core MVC and I'm applying Chart.js to render pictorial diagram.
The issues arises on the labeling of x-axis. When I manually write in JavaScript like this it is all done:

```
labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
```

But when I'm calling @ `ViewBag.Exponate` like this it doesn't show up:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate)
```

Here are the Controller codes:

```
 var recordList = _db.OrderHeader.Where(u=>u.UserId==sain.Value && u.ShopId==Convert.ToInt32(_LoadSessions)).GroupBy(x => x.OrderDate.ToString("MMMM"))
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();
            List<string> monthlists = recordList.Select(x => x.OrderDate.ToString("MMMM")).ToList();
                ViewBag.Exponate = string.Join(",", monthlists);

            var summation = _db.OrderHeader.Where(u => u.UserId == sain.Value && u.ShopId == Convert.ToInt32(_LoadSessions)).GroupBy(x => x.OrderDate)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    countIf = x.Sum(y => y.OrderTotal)
                }).ToList();

            List<string> values = summation.Select(x => x.countIf.ToString()).ToList();
            ViewBag.valuesX= string.Join(",", values);
```

Here is the view:

```
<script src="~/Charts/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/Charts/utils.js"></script>

<style>

    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
</style>

<div style="width:100%; color:white">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="background-color:#e8e2e2"></canvas>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<script>
        var MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        var config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate)],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    data: [
                      @ViewBag.valuesX
                    ],
                    fill: false,
                }, {
                    label: 'My Second dataset',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    data: [
                        @ViewBag.valuesX 
                    ],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Month'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Value'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
        };


</script>
```

So the problem is here:

```
labels: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate)],
```

If I put into like this:

```
labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
```

It works.

But I don't want that. I want labels to be loaded from my controller Lists Object as something like this:

```
labels: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate)],
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How does the resulting HTML look like when you use `labels: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your serialization is not producing a valid JavaScript array. Rather, it's producing output like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let data = {
        labels : January,February,March
    };
</script>
```

What you want instead is a JavaScript array of strings:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let data = {
        labels : ["January","February","March"]
    };
</script>
```

Solution: use Newtonsoft.Json for the serialization. E.g.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var monthlists = new List<string> { "January", "February", "March" };

    // ViewBag.Exponate = string.Join(",", monthlists);

    ViewBag.Exponate = 
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(monthlists);

    return View();
}
```

When you do that, then the following will produce the valid JavaScript array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let data = {
        labels : @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate)
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works Now !!

```
labels: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate) ,
```

I have to remove `[@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate)]` the Square brackets and leave to
 it to be

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Exponate)
```

and In controller

```
ViewBag.Exponate = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(monthlists);
```

Thanks alot guys!!